# Hibernate : How to get Named SQL Query resultset as List<Map<columnName,Value> instead of List<Object[]>

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, resultset, named-query

I wrote a named sql query in hibernate mapping file which return only few columns from different tables.

```
  <resultset name="employeeDetails">
     <return-scalar type="timestamp" column="joinDate"/>
     <return-scalar type="string" column="name"/>
     <return-scalar type="string" column="department"/>
     <return-scalar type="big_decimal" column="salary"/>
  </resultset>

  <sql-query name="getEmployeeDetails" resultset-ref="employeeDetails">
   <![CDATA[
    select ei.joinDate as joinDate, e.name as name, e.depatrment as department, e.salary as salary from Employee as e, Employee_Info as ei where ei.emp_id = e.id
    ]]>
  </sql-query>
```

When I called this query.

```
   final Query query = session.getNamedQuery("getEmployeeDetails");
   final List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>) query.list();
```

It returns List of Object Array. Is there any way to get this result set as List of Map with columnName as key and it value as Value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Query query=session.createSQLQuery(query); 
query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE); 
List<Map<String,Object>> aliasToValueMapList=query.list();
```